# vaadin cross form validation fails as bean not bound

Tags: java, forms, validation, vaadin

<vaadin.version>22.0.7</vaadin.version>

I have built a vaadin edit form with an attached Save button.
When the user clicks  'Save' I want to validate the form and then save the validated data to the bean.

This works as expected.

The problem comes when I went to add in cross field validation. In this case I want to validate that a start/end date pair are in the correct order.

The problem is that when I add the form validator, vaadin starts throwing exceptions when I call validate.

```java
@Override
    public void bindFields(CrudFieldBinder<DiscountCode> binder)
    {
        binder.forField(this.discountCode).asRequired("Please enter the unique Discount Code.").bind(
                DiscountCode::getDiscountCode,
                DiscountCode::setDiscountCode);

        binder.forField(this.startDate).asRequired("Please enter a Start Date.").bind(DiscountCode::getStartDate,
                DiscountCode::setStartDate);

        binder.forField(this.endDate).asRequired("Please enter an End Date.")
                .bind(DiscountCode::getEndDate,
                        DiscountCode::setEndDate);

        binder.withValidator(new DateRangeValidator());
        
    }
```

I've tried a few variations all with the same result. Here is the latest iteration:

```java
    protected void saveEdits(E currentEntity) {
        try
        {
            binder.writeBean(currentEntity);
        }
        catch (ValidationException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // this line throws the below error
        BinderValidationStatus<E> status = binder.validate();
 }
```

The call to writeBean runs without error but the call to binder.validate() fails with:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot validate binder: bean level validators have been configured but no bean is currently set
    at com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.Binder.validate(Binder.java:2479) ~[flow-data-9.0.8.jar:9.0.8]
    at com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.Binder.validate(Binder.java:2463) ~[flow-data-9.0.8.jar:9.0.8]
... EditorFormLayout.saveEdits(EditorFormLayout.java:92) ~[classes/:?]
```

This seems to suggest that form level validation only works if you make a call to setBean, however  my understanding is the call to setBean will result in the form autosaving rather than waiting for the user to click the save button.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a supported method for doing this.

I've raised a feature request here:
https://github.com/vaadin/platform/issues/2868

Here is my hack that relies on overloading the binder and making the validation method think a bean is bound.

````java
import com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.Binder;
import com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.BinderValidationStatus;


public class MyBinder<E> extends Binder<E>
{
    public MyBinder()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Apparently when doing cross field validation by calling
     * binder.withValidator there is no way to the list of errors back
     * due to the following issue.
     *   https://github.com/vaadin/platform/issues/2868
     *   
     *   Which essentially says that unless you are using setBean you can't
     *   do cross form validation.
     *   
     *   This code caches the bean sent to the binder when readBean is called
     *   and then uses that bean to fake a bound bean during validation.
     *   
     */
    private boolean validating = false;
    private E bean;

    @Override
    public void readBean(E bean)
    {
        this.bean = bean;
        super.readBean(bean);
    }

    @Override
    public void setBean(E bean)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("The MyBinder only works with read/writeBean");
    }

    @Override
    public E getBean()
    {
        if (validating)
        {
            return bean;
        }
        /// this call should always return null as setBean hasn't been
        // called but we do this try to reduce the likelihood of this overload
        // causing problems if someone accicentially uses this class
        // when using setBean.
        return super.getBean();
    }

    @Override
    public BinderValidationStatus<E> validate()
    {
        try
        {
            // force getBean to return a bean during validation.
            validating = true;
            return super.validate();
        }
        finally
        {
            validating = false;
        }

    }

}```
````